# creating an instance of another object in javascript

Tags: prototypejs, prototype-programming, javascript

I want to know whether this sentence is correct?

You can do:

```
var a = new A();
```

if and only if `A` is `instanceof Function`.

Simply you can create an instance of function and you know a function is an object. Why can't we create an instance of other user-defined objects? Like this:

```
var b={};
var c = new b();  //error
```

EDIT: How can I change `b` so that I can create an instance of that?

Comment: You mean, if you declare `a = {};`, for example?

Comment: Because instances need to be "constructed" from a `constructor` -- or a unit of work that is responsible for "creating" an object, in the literal sense of a "constructor" -- hence a `function`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually use `Object.create()` to have some sugar around ECMAscript's prototypal nature. Like

```
var b = { };
var c = Object.create( b );
```

Now, c will have `b` on its prototype chain. ECMAscript or more precisely, prototypal inheritance doesn't work exactly the same way as a "classical inheritance". By calling `new` when invoking a function, you actually receiving a newly created object aswell. You can modify and access that object via the `this` value within that such called *constructor function*.

However, you didn't inherit anything so far. You would need to create and fill the `.prototype` - object for your constructor function before you create instances of it. This pattern annoyed lots of people, so ES5 brought as a more convinient way to directly inherit from other objects using `Object.create()`.

Answer (score 4):

> Simply you can create an instance of function and you know a function is an object. Why can't we create an instance of other user-defined objects?

It’s not quite correct to say “you can create an instance of function”. The `new` keyword is a bit misleading - it makes JavaScript look like it implements object-orientation using classes, when in fact it doesn’t.

What you’re actually doing with `new A()` is creating an object using the constructor function `A`. The `new` keyword tells the JavaScript interpreter to return an object from `A` - specifically the object referred to as `this` inside of `A`.

> EDIT: How can I change `b` so that I can create an instance of that?

In your example, `b` is an object (`var b={};`). If you change `b` into a constructor function, then you can create objects using it. (By convention, constructor functions in JavaScript start with capital letters.)

So:

```
function B () {
}

var c = new B();
```

You can add things to the `prototype` object of `B`, and they’ll be accessible on `c` too (and on any other objects you create using `B`):

```
function B () {
}

B.prototype.NAME = 'B';

B.prototype.hello = function () {
    alert('Hello!');
}

var c = new B();
c.NAME // 'B'
c.hello() // alerts 'Hello!'
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:  The `new` operator requires its operand to have a special internal method `[[Construct]]` that generic objects do not have.

Long answer:

```
11.2.2 The new Operator
The production NewExpression : new NewExpression is evaluated as follows:
    1. Evaluate NewExpression.
    2. Call GetValue(Result(1)).
    3. If Type(Result(2)) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
    4. If Result(2) does not implement the internal [[Construct]] method, throw a TypeError exception.
    5. Call the [[Construct]] method on Result(2), providing no arguments (that is, an empty list of arguments).
    6. Return Result(5).

    The production MemberExpression : new MemberExpression Arguments is evaluated as follows:

    1. Evaluate MemberExpression.
    2. Call GetValue(Result(1)).
    3. Evaluate Arguments, producing an internal list of argument values (11.2.4).
    4. If Type(Result(2)) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
    5. If Result(2) does not implement the internal [[Construct]] method, throw a TypeError exception.
    6. Call the [[Construct]] method on Result(2), providing the list Result(3) as the argument values.
    7. Return Result(6).
```

Comment: How can I change `b` so that I can create an instance of that?

Comment: What are you /really/ trying to do?  Why are you trying to create such a beast?

Answer (score 1):

You can also  do

```
var b = new a.constructor();
```